# qsort of a structure in c++

Tags: c++, struct, qsort

I try to sort a structure but I have this error :

```
    error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<Node>’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, __compar_fn_t)’
  qsort(nodes,nodes.size(), sizeof(Node), dataClustering::compare);
```

This is my code :
compare function :

```
int compare(const void * node1, const void * node2){
    string name1 = ((const struct Node*)node1)->name;
    string name2 = ((const struct Node*)node2)->name;
    int start1 = ((const struct Node*)node1)->start;
    int start2 = ((const struct Node*)node2)->start;

    if(name1 <= name2 && start1 <= start2){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(name1 > name2 && start1 > start2){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }       
}
```

Call of compare in another function :

```
qsort(allNodes,allNodes.size(), sizeof(Node), compare);
```

And the header in .hpp file (I try to put it in static but this don't solve the error):

```
int compare(struct Node *, struct Node *);
```

Comment: TL;DR `C++` does not support implicit conversion of pointer to/fom `void *`

Comment: Listen to your compiler: `allNodes` is not a `void*`.

Comment: *Why* would you want to do that, rather than the much saner `std::sort(begin(nodes), end(nodes))`?

Comment: @MohitJain He is trying to implicitly convert a `vector` to `void*`...

Comment: @MohitJain One direction (*to* void*) is ok (of course only for pointers, not vectors)

Comment: @KerrekSB Because I have other elements in my struct and I want to sort just regarding name and start

Comment: @user3608663 then why not use `std::sort(begin(nodes), end(nodes), compare_functor)`?

Comment: Never use `qsort` in C++. If you don't know how to use `std::sort` for your purposes, ask how to use `std::sort`, not how to use `qsort`.

Comment: Ok, my mistake was that I declare my function_compare in a class. Is it possible that was the cause of the error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass vector to C-style sort, for example, like this:

```
qsort(&allNodes[0], allNodes.size(), sizeof(Node), compare);
```

You would be better off using `std::sort`, which works with vectors natively:

```
bool compareNodes(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) {
    return (lhs.name < rhs.name)
        || (lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.start < rhs.start);
}
...
std::sort(allNodes.begin(), allNodes.end(), compareNodes);
```

in C++11/C++14 you can define comparison as a lambda, too:

```
std::sort(allNodes.begin(), allNodes.end(), [] (const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    return (lhs.name < rhs.name)
        || (lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.start < rhs.start);
});
```

(the code above uses `auto` for lambda arguments, a C++14 feature).

Comment: I think `allNodes.data()` is preferable to `&allNodes[0]`? Ultimately the same thing either way, I suppose.

Comment: s/C++11/C++14; auto for lambda arguments is from C++14.

Comment: thanks ! I did it and it's working. I had just one more error that I declare compareNode in a class and that was not working... Now it's ok, thanks

Comment: Rather than reinventing the comparison algorithm, you could also use `std::tie(lhs.name, lhs.start) < std::tie(rhs.name, rhs.start)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just sort, use

```
#include <algorithm>
...
bool myfunction (const Node &lhs, const Node &lhs) {
  if(lhs.name < rhs.name) return true;
  return (lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.start < rhs.start));
}
...
std::sort(allNodes.begin(), allNodes.end(), compare_func);
```

Further read: [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

If you want to use cstyle `qsort`(which I suggest you should not), add a wrapper function to do the conversion of `void *` to `Node *` and change the first argument of `qsort` to `static_cast<void *>(&allNodes[0])`

Comment: If you want to use cstyle `qsort`, slap yourself on the wrist, hard. Here, FTFY.

Comment: @n.m. Your suggestion is much better

Comment: Note also that std::sort is faster than C qsort. (due to e.g. compile-time binding of comparison operation etc).

Comment: I would write `myfunction`: `return std::tie(lhs.name, lhs.start) < std::tie(rhs.name, rhs.start);`

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you

```
cannot convert ‘std::vector<Node>’ to ‘void*’
```

and thus, a `std::vector<Node>` cannot possibly be a suitable first argument to a function like `qsort` with signature

```
void (void*, size_t, size_t, __compar_fn_t)
```

While there are things you could do to use `qsort` here, you really shouldn't: you should use `std::sort` from the C++ standard library:

```
using std::sort;
sort(begin(allNodes), end(allNodes), compare_function);
```

Here, `compare_function` should be a function that acts like `<` and takes two arguments of the appropriate type (e.g. the actual type of the objects you're sorting or `const` references to them, not pointers to them or `void` pointers) and returns `bool` if the first argument is less than the second. (`compare_function` doesn't actually have to be a function: it can also be any object that has an appropriate `operator()` or a lambda)

Comment: I don't think you need that `using` declaration there; ADL will already find the right name.

Comment: @Kerrek: You don't in this particular case, but you would in some other cases (e.g. sorting a C-style array with the default comparison), so I thought it worth posting the general pattern.